# Jquery only affect one element in a class being hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure if this is possible.
I want to select all elements with a class name and only affect the one element being hovered at that time and not the whole class. i can't use ids since they are a lot.

```
 $('.hideme').hover(function(){
        $('.hideme').hide();
    });
```

and then.

```
<div class='hideme'></div>
```

when the above hides, the following shouldn't hide.

```
<div class='hideme'></div>
<div class='hideme'></div>
<div class='hideme'></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you try to `hide` by using `clss name`, then DOM will hide all the element with same name.

So you have to use `this` keyword for selecting current `hovered` element.

Try following:

```
$('.hideme').hover(function(){
        $(this).hide();
});
```